# Corners on windows do not render properly (gnome on ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

[image: Angles]

I'm getting window corners that are not properly rendered. I tried using lightdm, gdm, gnome classic, and gnome(3). I finally ended up with flashback - it starts and draws with no problems (except sigsegv accurate after install and just the 1st time).

Comment: By "angles", do you mean "corners"?  Is the issue the sharp black bit behind the rounded corner of the window?

Comment: Yes, black corners. (sorry for my english)

Comment: No worries.  I reformulated the text somewhat. Does the last sentence mean that `flashback` does not work, or that the installation fails the 1st time only, or that it properly renders the corners but that there's some other issue with it? I was unsure what you meant by using the word "accurate".

Comment: Well, flashback is the only thing that works(as well as unity), just throws exception after install and then works normal(I don't know why). It's just sad, that gnome3 and gnome-classic have this very little minus(black corners).

Comment: I mean, flashback and unity work with no black corners, but gnome3 and gnome - classic have black corners.

Comment: Consider updating the text of the question itself if you feel it has to be clarified. Don't add clarifications in comments.